# Arens regularity of $\mathrm{BV}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, bounded-variation

$\DeclareMathOperator\BV{BV}$A Banach algebra $A$ is called [**Arens regular**](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Arens_regularity) if the two canonical multiplications on the double dual $A^{**}$ coincide. Let [$\BV(\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV(%CE%A9)_is_a_Banach_algebra) denote the Banach algebra of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ which are continuous and of bounded variation.

> Is $\BV(\mathbb{R})$ Arens regular?

Here's how far I've gotten until now:

- I have not seen the question mentioned in any of the literature so far. In particular, it doesn't seem to be in [Palmer's book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/banach-algebras-and-the-general-theory-of-algebras/F288B45DB1650AA9B71E6F2A4EB0E90A).
- Since $C^*$-algebras are Arens regular, it would be enough to realize $\BV(\mathbb{R})$ as a closed subalgebra of a $C^*$-algebra, or equivalently to represent it on a Hilbert space.
- Characterizing the dual space $\BV(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ is [an open problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391284/the-dual-of-mathrmbv), but I'm not sure if this includes the case $n = 1$. If so, I'm hoping that my question might still have a known answer that doesn't depend on a characterization of the dual first.

Answer (score 5):

Writing this in a hurry on my way to a ritual English social cohesion exercise, so apologies for the lack of formatting and the sketchy nature of claims and references.

---

I think it might be "known" to experts that this Banach algebra is not Arens regular, without it being written down anywhere. My reasoning is that there should be a **surjective** continuous homomorphism from $\mathrm{BV}(\Bbb R)$ to $\mathrm{bv}(\Bbb N)$, given by restriction of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb N$. Now Arens regularity passes to quotients, so if $\mathrm{BV}(\Bbb R)$ were Arens regular then $\mathrm{bv}(\Bbb N)$ would be Arens regular. But $\mathrm{bv}(\Bbb N)$ is isomorphic to the unitization of the convolution algebra $A=\ell^1({\mathbb N}_\min)$ where ${\mathbb N}_\min$ is the semigroup obtained by equipping ${\mathbb N}$ with $\min$ as the product, and it is known that $A$ fails to be Arens regular. I don't know what the earliest reference for this last fact is: a more general construction for weighted analogues of $\ell^1({\mathbb N}_\min)$ can be found in the [recent PhD thesis of M. E. Celorrio](https://doi.org/10.17635/lancaster/thesis/2008), see Prop 3.3.1, but the unweighted case has certainly been known for a long time.

On a side note: Arens regularity is much weaker than being isomorphic to a closed subalgebra of $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$, so while it is possible to prove Arens regularity by embedding as a closed subalgebra of $B(H)$ this is usually asking too much.

Comment: Thank you! I see that this is your student's thesis. Unfortunately the download doesn't work for me, but I'll try again some other time. I'll have to digest this a bit, and perhaps you'll want to write another answer with your standard account which I can accept then?

Comment: Do the Arens products coincide more frequently on the sequential weak-* closure of a Banach algebra in its double dual? I suspect that this "sequential Arens regularity" is equivalent to the usual Arens regularity because of the characterization of the latter in terms of exchanging limits of sequences, but I'm not sure.